# Notepad++ Highlight Matching Quotes?

Tags: editor, notepad++

I love that Notepad++ highlights matching braces **{ }**, brackets **[ ]**, and parenthesis **( )** -- when I click one of those characters, its match (if exists) highlights with whatever style I have configured.

How can I add double quotes **" "**, single quotes **' '**, and angular brackets **< >**, etc. to the list of characters that highlight when clicked?

I've searched through many XML config files, python files, the lib2to3 python tree code, NPP plugins, their support forum, and I am left wanting...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/561798/how-to-make-and-syntax-highlight-strings-for-python-in-notepad

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @MPatel - I'm thinking that's for changing the code between the single quotes to a different color than normal text. James is asking for a way to highlight the pair of " ", ' ', and <>.

Comment: I would say there's probably no reason to, but that could depend on the language. From the ones *I* use the entire string within the ' or " pairs is highlighted, color dependent on your theme, so you can just look to where that ends. As far as the < and > is concerned, I would imagine the reason why it's not that way, again in the languages I use, is because they don't need to always appear in pairs to be valid code. Therefore the parser that determined if it was valid pairs would probably be pretty involved.

Comment: @MPatel - Chief is right; the styler will color code between those characters, and that's what I've done for now, but I'd like to have the effect of clicking one (say) opening double quote and having it simply highlight the next discovered double quote without having to permanently color the text in between. Just like **{ }** works.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Thanks for responding. If the parser is already stylizing text between the characters, isn't it already doing the dirty work? I was hoping there was a list of "highlight matching characters" somewhere in a config I could append. I'm dealing with long regex sequences, some with **"** **'** **< >** characters that need escaped, so the matching highlight would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, when it comes to ' and " the work is already done; I'm only saying "they" decided it would be better to highlight the entire text as opposed to just the char pairs. No work, that I've seen however, is done on <>. It's available in better products like Eclipse so it's obviously considered important for some, but apparently not a high priority for NP++. Perhaps developing a plug-in is in your near future.